# Space in directory name creating problem

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to build some code and the location where the compiler is present has a space in it 'blahblah/Source Code/blahblah' .I am not sure how to add this to the environment variable.I use bash and tried to use the normal

> export PATH="$PATH:/blahblah/Source Code/blahblah"

but it doesnt seem to work(I also tried using \before spaces).Throws me errors like No such file or directory.Am I missing out on something?

Comment: Seems like it should work, but are you sure the executable for the compiler is in this "Source Code" directory?

Comment: @John: I think you mean, "are you sure the executable is in this 'Source Code/blahblah' directory?"  (Maybe "blahblah" is the binary... which would explain the problem)

Comment: Did you try the backslash before the space with *single* quotes, not double quotes?

Comment: The executable for the compiler is indeed in the correct location.And i did check using echo $PATH and it shows me the given path .Infact also shows me the \ version also.Does this mean the error is somewhere else and not with the locations?

Comment: This ought to work just fine, your problem can not be because of the space character. Could you post more detailed info? Does the executable have proper permissions?

Comment: You didn't provide enough information.  What's the command you're running?  How is the compiler being invoked?  Are you executing it directly or is it being run from a script or an IDE?  If run from a script, what are the contents of the script?  What's the exact error message?  What is generating the error message?

Comment: try ls -l $PATH to make sure the file's really where you think it is

Comment: Thanks for the help.It did appear that problem was indeed the space.I wonder why using \ etc didnt work.Finally I had to rename it to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a little experimentation on my own:

```
$ mkdir 'Source Code'
$ cd Source\ Code/
$ vim testme.pl
$ chmod 755 testme.pl
$ cat testme.pl 
#! /usr/bin/perl
print "I worked\n";
$ ./testme.pl
I worked
$ cd ..
$ export PATH="$PATH:/home/bchittenden/Source Code"
$ testme.pl 
I worked
```

This indicates that the problem is not the whitespace in $PATH... bash seems to handle that correctly... you'll have to give us more information.